# What display is used in remote control

Tags: display

I'm making a device which requires a display, and the display I want is similar to what goes into remote control of air conditioners.

What are these kind of displays, and how do they have some special icons built into them? I know lcd modules available for arduino etc can be an alternative, but I like the look of ones in remote control.

Comment: LCD modules can be made with any icons you want ... for a price. That's probably how your aircon did it. Unless you're making a million, you probably want to use standard bitmap displays instead (use software to draw your own bitmapped icons)

Comment: I saw a product which uses good display with lots of icons etc but it's not a product which sells in large quantity or is costly. Was wondering if its really too costly to create such displays then. The one I saw was 10mm x 8mm approx, and cannot cost over 10 usd

Comment: They are LCDs with custom glass. Usually they contain just the bare glass and the LCD glass driver electronics are on the PCB. Modern microcontrollers can have an LCD glass driver built-in, but if not, then you need a separate chip between your MCU and LCD glass.

Comment: Cost of making custom LCD glass is not that bad. Figure a few thousand USD for MOQ + NRE costs.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany a bit better than I thought.

Comment: Make a functional prototype with a graphic LCD or OLED, then when you have funding look into getting a custom one.  Or make a cruder prototype that doesn't have the little widgets on it but just key information.  They're not actually all that great an idea, I just had to look up the heatpump manual to find out if the snowflake widget was for winter or for cooling.  Turns out that snowflake means making feel it like winter during summer, and the sunburst means making it feel like summer during winter, but the raindrop means making it feel dry when it's raining, which breaks the pattern.

Comment: The tooling fee for a cheap 1" x 1" B&W old-school LCD screen is getting down to about $1000 these days (made in China of course).   Displays will be about $0.30-$0.50 / each in quantities of maybe 10-50k.   My info is from last time I quoted one, about 2 years ago.    Thats just the glass of course, needs connection (zebra or heat-seal) and a controller IC.

Comment: I believe Dave Jones did a video about ordering custom LCDs. I definitely recall that the price for a custom design was not too bad - something like $500 (once, not per display).

Comment: Also, all of these are answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only custom parts of a custom LCD are its size, and the transparent ITO electrodes on the glass. Typically, the electrodes are created with photolitography, which is somewhat similar to the process used for custom PCBs.

For LCDs, the setup costs are much higher than actual production costs, so you would not use them unless you planned to make a certain number of devices. The process is not as automated as for PCBs.

Dave Jones made several videos about a custom LCD for his USB power supply:

[EEVblog #1055 - How to Design a Custom LCD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvxgl-9tNM)
"How to design a custom multiplexed LCD display.
Dave takes you through what is required to design your own custom LCD display and what consideration you need for manufacturing and choosing an LCD display driver."

[EEVblog #1074 - Custom LCD Design - Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10D5jpO45Lo)
"Looking at the manufacturers datasheet for approval, and test design considerations."

[EEVblog #1105 - $100 Custom LCD Design - Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA5vlDdpbkw)
"The $100 low cost custom LCD finally arrives!
Will it work as intended?"
(Five modules for $138, including $33 shipping.)